# Why mathematical structure is known as structure

Tags: discrete-mathematics, terminology

Why discrete structures like group, monoid, field is known as structures. Due to what parameters discrete structures are known as structures.

Comment: they are sets with operations and rules

Comment: In my experience, "structure" colloquially refers to the collection of generalized properties of an object, rather than anything formal.  We might talk of "algebraic structure", "topological structure", "geometric structure" or [in my experience more rarely] "analytic structure".  This means, for instance, that while "is a group" implies algebraic structure, it would be awkward [to my ear] to say a particular group "is a structure" (unless we're stretching it to mean the isomorphism class of that group)

Comment: Can I say space is a structure. Example Einstein's space, Hilbert space same way Galois Field (GF) is a structure?

Answer (score 4):

From Merriam-Webster's [definition of structure](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/structure):

> 2b: something arranged in a definite pattern of organization

or maybe

> 4b: organization of parts as dominated by the general character of the whole

which definitely describes mathematical structures.